# How to set scroll bar ever visible?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

How to set the scroll bar visible in a div ?

```
.table-wrapper.grouped {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

it shows scroll bar only if I try to scroll.

Comment: "ever visible", you wanna hide the scroll bar ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui I'm sorry.. I edited the question

Comment: Using `overflow-y: scroll;` will always display a vertical scroll bar. Your CSS is correct. But i think that might there it's being overwritten by another class. Try adding `!important` after `scroll`.

Comment: @A.Ortogni please could you make a snippet displaying a [mcve] as the code you have supplied should do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLVED***

```
/* width */
.table-wrapper.grouped::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
.table-wrapper.grouped::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
.table-wrapper.grouped::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ccc; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
.table-wrapper.grouped::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #fff; 
}
```

**Notice:** It works only in chrome and Safari